# Can the preposition "with" be used to introduce the instrument of calling, talking, listening etc

Tags: prepositions

When we bring in the modal auxiliary verbs or verb phrases to be used with "to call", "to talk", "to listen", "to watch" "to email" and the like, would it be correct or, at least acceptable, to put it this way?

1. "You can call your friend with the/a phone" ("You can call your friend both with your cell phone and housebound handset").

Or should it be said: "You can call your friend on the phone ("You can call your friend both on your cell phone and housebound handset")?

2. "You can talk with your friend with the/a phone" ("You can talk with your friend both with your cell phone and housebound handset").

Or should it be said: "You can talk with your friend on the phone ("You can talk with your friend both on your cell phone and housebound handset")?

3. "You can listen to your favourite songs with the/a radio" ("You can listen to your favourite songs with that old radio of your grandfather").

Or should it be said: "You can listen to your favourite songs on the radio" ("You can listen to your favourite songs on that old radio of your grandfather")?

4. "You can watch your favourite programmes with the/a TV" ("You can watch your favourite programmes with that old TV of your grandfather").

Or should it be only said: "You can watch your favourite programmes on TV" ("You can watch your favourite programmes on that old TV of your grandfather")?

And does the article make a difference for settling on whether to use "with" or not?

Comment: *"You can watch your favourite programmes with the/a TV"* is a bit "weird", because (to some, not all native Anglophones) ***with*** implies a slightly different relationship than ***on*** (more "actively" making use of the equipment, rather than it just being the metaphorical location of video content). But because ***with*** is an uncommon "marked" usage, different people might asssign different possible meanings. Assuming they heard it from a native speaker, obviously. If a *learner* said it, I probably wouldn't think anything of it (I might echo back agreement using ***on*** as a courtesy)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you. What possible meanings might be assigned to "with" being related to "TV"?        
 And what with the rest of the patterns? Can they have the right to exist?

Comment: As implied above, by far the most likely explanation if all I've got to go on is written text rather than *how they speak* would simply be "non-Anglophone writer". That's all you need to know, really.

Comment: Or just maybe someone who continuously uses online audio/video on their smartphone might say *"I prefer to watch the news **with** my TV"* to emphasize the *different* medium being used.

Comment: You asked a good question, but note that you just need to figure out how native people make sentences. And memorise their word order. Sometimes It's mostly about memory and literature than grammar or special rule.

Answer (score 1):

In all the examples, "with" is OK, but maybe slightly less common as "on", and possibly adds a tiny chance of confusion.

Consider these two sentences:

1. You can stream movies on a smart TV.
2. You can stream movies with a smart TV

It is very common to use "on" when speaking about the use of devices for listening, viewing and communicating. It is less common -- but not incorrect -- to use "with" in these cases. I think it is because "with" also has a meaning of "along side of" or "in addition to" as well as the meaning "by using".

In all the examples given, an alternative wording using forms of "use" is clear and unambiguous. "On" and "with" sentences are OK too. However, when "with" is next to the object (your friend), it can make it sound like the friend is the one "with" the device.

```
*You can use my phone to call your friend. You can call your friend with my phone. You can call your friend on my phone.*

*You can use a cell or landline phone to talk with your friend. You can talk to your friend on a cell or landline phone. You can talk to your friend with a cell or landline phone [but it could be understood to mean the friend has the two types of phones].*

*You can use that old radio of your grandfather's to listen to your favourite songs. You can listen to your favorite songs on that old radio of your grandfather's. You can listen to your favorite songs with that old radio of your grandfather's.*


"You can watch your favourite programmes with the/a TV" ("You can watch your favourite programmes with that old TV of your grandfather").
```

Comment: Thank you! You have put me up to a very interesting apprehension of another possible situation referring to a friend that is having the device by him.